# Perl one-liner for parsing host names from ssh config file

Tags: parsing, perl, configuration

Here is the working code (intended to be executed with `perl -e '<code>' ~/.ssh/config`):

Actual version:

```perl
while(<>){if(/^Host (.+)/){$_=$1;foreach $i(/([^ ]+)/g){$h{$i}=1}}}print "$_ " for keys %h;
```

Identical version with whitespace for reading:

```perl
while(<>) {
    if(/^Host (.+)/) {
        $_=$1;
        foreach $i(/([^ ]+)/g) {
            $h{$i}=1
        }
    }
}
print "$_ " for keys %h;
```

I'm sort of a perl newbie.  Is `$_=$1` kosher?  Is there a straight-forward way to do this with a single regex?  Is there anything else I should be doing better here?

**Example input output:**

For a config file with contents like this:

```
Host build
    HostName build.myserver.com
Host build build.myserver.com
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/build
Host tunnel
    LocalForward 6397 redis.production.com:6379
```

The output should be (order is not required, trailing space is not required but acceptable):

```
build build.myserver.com tunnel
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use something like

```
perl -lane '@h{@F[1..$#F]}=()if/^Host\b/;END{$,=" ";print keys %h}' -- file
```

or

```
perl -lane '@h{ @F[ 1 .. $#F ] } = () if /^Host\b/;
            END {
                $, = " ";
                print keys %h;
            }' -- file
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`s
- `-n` runs the code for each line of the input
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- the hash `%h` is populated by all the non-whitepsace strings following `Host`
- at the end, all the keys are printed separated by space

Comment: Commenting some other things I learned from this answer that I didn't know previously: `$#array` returns the last index of an array, `$,` is the "output field separator" printed automatically between fields, `END{}` gives a block of code that is executed when exiting, useful for doing final one-time code while still using the `-n` option.

Comment: can shave a few characters there by switching to `print "@{[ EXPR ]}"` and using `eof` in place of an END block.  And the spaces after `-e` and `keys` are optional.  `perl -lane'@h{@F[1..$#F]}=()if/^Host\b/;eof&&print"@{[keys%h]}"' -- file`